# Access 2D array from another function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-definition

I can access array using pointer notion in the function where the array is declared. But, I can not access from another function which throws an error: **indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)**. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int ROW = 3;
const int COL = 3;

void printArray(int *ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ROW][COL];
    int count = 2;

    // initialize 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    // print 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            // printf("%i\t", arr[i][j]); // using array
            printf("%i\t", *(*(arr + i) + j)); // using pointer

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n---------printing using function------------\n");
    printArray(&arr[0][0]);
}

void printArray(int *ptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("%i\t", *(*(ptr + i) + j)); // not working as expected
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

How can i solve this problem? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters pay attention to that in C these declarations

```
const int ROW = 3;
const int COL = 3;
```

do not declare integer constants. So your program deals with a variable length array.

If you want to define integer constants you could write for example

```
enum { ROW = 3, COL = 3 };
```

Nevertheless either declare and define the function the following way

```
void printArray( int ( *ptr )[COL], int row );
```

and

```
void printArray( int ( *ptr )[COL], int row )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("%i\t", *(*(ptr + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
printArray( arr, ROW );
```

Or if to use your declaration then the function definition will look like

```
void printArray(int *ptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("%i\t", *( ptr + i * COL + j ) );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`*(*(ptr + i) + j)` de-refereneces the pointer with two levels of indirection, which isn't possible since it only got one, being an `int*`.

In general, refrain from crazy pointer arithmetic expressions and use readable array indexing instead: `ptr[i + j]`. Though your calculation is wrong too, it should be `ptr[i*COL + j]`

---

Though the above is referred to as "mangled 2D arrays" and is correct but kind of archaic C. By using pointers to variable-length arrays (VLA) as done in modern C programming, we can turn the code much more readable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int ROW = 3;
const int COL = 3;

void printArray(size_t row, size_t col, int array[row][col]);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ROW][COL];
    int count = 2;

    // initialize 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    // print 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            // printf("%i\t", arr[i][j]); // using array
            printf("%i\t", *(*(arr + i) + j)); // using pointer

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n---------printing using function------------\n");
    printArray(ROW, COL, arr);
}

void printArray(size_t row, size_t col, int array[row][col])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%i\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```